# Webconfig ConnectionString to connect SQL Server 2008 from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

What is connection string for the following SQL server 2008 properties:

DB Name : testDB

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this connection string:

```
Server=K-PC;Database=testDB;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

You can find more details on connection strings in this link: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working. your link is very nice :)